# llvm toy example error

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I am trying to run the make file of the toy example given [here](http://gnuu.org/2009/09/18/writing-your-own-toy-compiler/7), but it gives me the following error:

```
g++ -o parser parser.o codegen.o main.o tokens.o corefn.o native.o  `llvm-config
--libs` `llvm-config --ldflags` -lpthread -ldl -L/usr/bin -lz -lncurses -rdynamic

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lncurses
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:31: recipe for target 'parser' failed
make: *** [parser] Error 1
```

The software I am using is:

- clang version 3.8.0-2ubuntu4 (tags/RELEASE_380/final)
- Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
- Thread model: posix
- InstalledDir: /usr/bin

Ubuntu is a virtual machine running on Windows 8.1.

Any comment will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you think the error message is telling you? Why do you think it's failing?

Comment: Your link is not working so I cannot see what's used in the original. Do you have these libraries called `z` (??) and `ncurses` installed?

Comment: This is the link http://gnuu.org/2009/09/18/writing-your-own-toy-compiler/7/

Comment: YES it works ... Thank you so much

Comment: If you found a solution: it is allowed to [post an answer to your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). That could be helpful for others with the same problem. As a new user, you will have to wait a couple of days, but then you can even [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer), which shows others that this question has an answer that helped.